# how can i convert a bitmap to mat VB.net

Tags: vb.net

i am working in a project where i  have to convert a bitmap image from a screenshot to a mat format directly in order to use it with engu opencv. it only works when i save the image and call it with New Mat() funtion.

```
Public Function ScreenShot() As Bitmap
    Dim screenSize As Size = New Size(My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Width, 
    My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Height)

    Dim screenGrab As New Bitmap(My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Width, My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Height)

    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenGrab)

    g.CopyFromScreen(New Point(0, 0), New Point(0, 0), screenSize)

   screenGrab.Save("C:\Users\Desktop\test.png")

   imgOriginal = New Mat("C:\Users\Desktop\test.png")
```

screengrab is the bitmap but how can i use it directly as a mat format without saving it?.
 i think this saving operation could damage the hard drive because it is saving and reading this every second.

Comment: `Dim emguCVImage as Image(Of Bgr, Byte)  = new Image(Of Bgr, byte)(bitmap) dim matFromBitmap as Mat = emguCVImage.Mat`. [EMGU: Working with Images](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images)

Comment: it show me a message"Value of type bitmap cannot be converted to image" this is what i did:          Dim emguCVImage As Image(Of [Structure].Bgr, Byte) = New Image(Of Bgr, Byte)(ScreenShot)
        Dim matFromBitmap As Mat = emguCVImage.Mat